# Any alternative function for the resizeToMaxAsync in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am getting the type error while using the function resizeToMaxAsync() in NodeJs

- Node version- 10.0.1
- using opencv4nodejs (where as the opencv is not working with node 10 version)

> TypeError: img.resizeToMaxAsync is not a function

while printing the output coming from the img is as

> Promise {< pending >}

The main goal to access the pre-built and trained with images machine learning model (custom vision model)where as it is in (model.pb) format and having the labels.txt file for the model

Comment: There is no `resizeToMaxAsync` in Node.js as is, can you please state what library you're using, and show your code please.

Comment: Post the code in here, do not post links to code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an `img`, you're passing a `Promise`, and there is no `resizeToMaxAsync` method in a `promise`. You have to wait until that promise resolves.

```
testData.forEach(async (data) => {
  const img = await cv.imreadAsync(data.image); // Wait until image is read
  console.log(img); // Not a promise
  console.log('%s: ', data.label);
  const predictions = await classifyImg(img);

  /* ... */
});
```

And then:

```
const imgResized = (await img.resizeToMaxAsync(maxImgDim)).padToSquare(white);
```

Comment: Then it showing an error as   const imgResized = (await img.resizeToMaxAsync(maxImgDim)).padToSquare(white);  

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at img

Comment: which error.¡, you have to make the function an `async` one

Comment: yeah the error has cleared where as we need to get rid of **await** and put as __const imgResized = img.resizeToMaxAsync(maxImgDim).padToSquare(white);__